# How to detect if an iOS app (made with unity) gets closed?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am making an iOS app with unity, and I want it to detect if the app is closing the app or using it just in the background. By the way im coding in c#.

appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you could unity Application.quitting, it's an event called whenever the app is closing, add your own event on there and you can detect if it's quitting
(Doc Link : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-quitting.html)
Example:

```
static void QuitDetect()
{
    Debug.Log("App is Closing");
}

[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
static void RunOnStart()
{
    Application.quitting += QuitDetect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! :)